# Custom $index name in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code written in JADE that uses two ngRepeat directives, like this:

```
table
    tr(ng-repeat="item in items track by $index")
       td: .dropdown
           button.btn.btn-default(data-toggle="dropdown") Choose One
           ul.dropdown-menu
               li(ng-repeat="option in item.options")
                  // I need this $index's value comes from the first ng-repeat above
                  a(ng-click="changeOption(item, option, $index)")
```

Tag `<a>` have a `ng-click` directive that calls `changeOption(item, option, $index)`

The problem is that I need `$index` from the FIRST `ng-repeat` directive in `changeOption()` function instead of the second one. Can I change `$index` to another name or assign it to another variable so that I can access it in the second iteration?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` (I'm answering in HTML format):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-init="firstIndex = $index">
    <!-- Then use it here -->
    <a ng-click="changeOption(item, option, firstIndex)"></a>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to use `ng-init`, use `ng-repeat`'s expression support for *key/value* access.  While you're still using an array, they *key* will be the actual index.

docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
tr(ng-repeat="(t1, category) in vc.listData track by $index"
   td: .dropdown
       button.btn.btn-default(data-toggle="dropdown") Choose One
       ul.dropdown-menu
           li(ng-repeat="(t2, option) in item.options")
              a(ng-click="changeOption(item, option, t1)")
```